# Is this valid SQL?

Tags: sql, syntax

I'd like to update a table row where:
Either `statement1 is true` OR `statement2 is true`
AND independent of which one of those are true, `statement3 is also true`.

Would this be a valid way of writing this SQL statement?

```
$upadte = "UPDATE table SET 
    header = 'value'
    WHERE (statment1 = 'true' OR statment2 = 'true') AND statement3 = 'true'";
```

Comment: Execute it and tell us what you find!

Comment: are statement1,2 and 3 all column names?

Comment: if `statement1` is a column of type `varchar` (or other character types) then this should be OK. What happened when you tried?

Comment: Logically it should work correct

Comment: no, it looks like an assign of string to a variable in PHP. The literal you are assigning looks like syntatically correct SQL. However, the naming of the schema is inconsistent and misspelled, this may or may not match your database.

Comment: I don't see this question being of use to anyone, even the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the SQL is correct in the where part, but I think the 'true' must be true without "'" because if it's wrapped in '' will be interpreted as a string expresion rather than a boolean. The (A OR B) will return true if A or B are true, and if they are true. This condition is checked first because of the parenthesis. Then the thir statetment will be checked and if is true, the complete expression will return true.

```
$upadte = "UPDATE table SET 
    header = 'value'
    WHERE (statment1 = true OR statment2 = true) AND statement3 = true";
```

Comment: Not all DBMS support a `boolean` data type. So `'true'` might very well be the correct way for the DBMS the OP is using.

Comment: Although, if there is no boolean type, `condition = 1` is more likely than `condition = 'true'`